# Center-Rotating a Square

Tags: c#, rotation, shapes

So I saw here, someone asked it before, but I'm new at C-Sharp (C#) and I don't really understand how it works.

Code Update:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(200, 255, 140, 140);


private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(rect.X, rect.Y);
        e.Graphics.RotateTransform(180F);
        e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-rect.X, -rect.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
        e.Graphics.ResetTransform();
    }



private void kilepes_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
    }

     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now it makes the square rotate, but not around its center. It rotates around its upper left corner, so its not good for me. What to change in the code to make it work?

Comment: I don't suppose you can use WPF?

Comment: The easiest solution would to go back to your teacher and ask him to explain how to use the solutions he proposed.

Comment: The sad thing is, He wants Me to make it without giving Me any help so, I asked You guys.

Comment: If WinForms, start by wiring up the Paint() event of your Form.  In that event, use the supplied `e.Graphics` to draw with.  Good luck!

Comment: I thougt You can give me more information.

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you. At *least* get the first one done and then ask a *specific* question about how to rotate it.

Comment: We can write your homework, but that is neither the point of homework nor of this site. - Here are the things you will need: The `Paint` event and its parameter `e.Graphics`; the method `Graphics.DrawRectangle`, the `Size` of the `Rectangle`, two `Points`: its upper left corner, its center, the methods `Graphics.TranslateTransform` and `Graphics.RotateTransform` and  `Graphics.ResetTransform`. Also a `Pen`.. and the angle you want to rotate by

Comment: Wow! Okay thanks, i will try these! And I need to write that to Paint event too?

Well wait. I want to make a button to make the rotation, so i think I should write to Button.Click

Comment: Yes, all drawing happens there in WinForms. The Button would change the angle and then `Invalidate` whichever control you paint on, in your case the form, ie call `this.Invalidate` which triggers the paint event.

Comment: Once you've gotten some code down, and run into a problem, please **EDIT** your question above to include your current code and your specific problem.

Comment: The first thing and also an __amazingly hard one__ in programming is to know __exactly what you want__ to do. Maybe you only are supposed to rotate by 90 degrees? In which case all you need is the location / top left corner and the size..?

Comment: I have edited my question, i need to rotate 180° and draw it degree by degree. Now the code ask me for: System.Drawing.Drawing2D.MatrixOrder order

Comment: Not quite. Look at this [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/a0z3f662%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)!

Comment: In general: Translate, Rotate, then Draw.  Question, though, are you going to rotate around the **corner**, or around the **center** of your rectangle?

Comment: I want to rotate it around its center.

Comment: Which then is where the `TranslateTransform` must move the origin. So you need to calculate the coordinates of the Center, which will involve the `ClientSize` of the `Form` and the `Size` of your `Rectangle`...

Comment: In that case, I recommend you define your rectangle as being at (-70, -70) with your width of 140x140.  Then move the origin to where ever you would like the center of the rectangle to appear with TranslateTransform.  After the translation, you rotate, then draw.

Comment: Damn. I'm trying so hard to understand all this, but all the c# is very new for me. :/ I can draw the square, and nothing else :/

Comment: That is one option. I find it easier to do it this way: translate, rotate, translateback, draw, reset:     `e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(center.X, center.Y);
    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(-center.X, -center.Y);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, rect);
    e.Graphics.ResetTransform();`

Comment: __Don't worry__, rotation is not exactly the simplest thing to do, unless you know the tricks..

Comment: And where to put that code? How i can start the rotate with button?

Comment: It would be in the Paint() event, just like your other code is.  Additionally, just as you defined your Pen and Rectangle at Class level, you should also define some kind of variable out there to store the current rotation angle.  That way your Button can modify it and tell the Form to redraw itself with `this.Invalidate();`.

Comment: Notice how you are getting closer to your aim: Now you tell us that the Button is not supposed to __rotate__ the Rectangle but to __start__ the Rotation.. which eventually will lead to a `Timer` and its `Tick` event where you will add 1 degree to the angle and invalidate the form... I'm off now, time for bed :-)

Comment: Obviously i wanted to write that! Now the new square is just at the upper left corner of the original square that i drew. Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: So i tried to add a timer, and i managed it rotates around its upper left corner on each button click :|

But what i exactly want: When program loads, only see one square, then on btn click start rotate it 360° around its center

Comment: + when its rotating around its center, i want to see that new squares when its rotated

Comment: I found a pictue: i link it https://www.google.hu/search?q=rotating+square+gif&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=859&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=OwqAVOT4JKncywPUiYGAAQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=EcJZelVZsi6uzM%253A%3BU0TGbwuJh9YYdM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fupload.wikimedia.org%252Fwikipedia%252Fcommons%252F6%252F6e%252FRotating_Square.gif%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fcommons.wikimedia.org%252Fwiki%252FFile%253ARotating_Square.gif%3B488%3B488

Comment: Added a code update, still not working perfectly.

Comment: Welcome back.  So close!  In the Tick() event, all you need to do is increment angle and invalidate.  Get rid of that other code in there.  For the rectangle, you need to translate to the **CENTER** of it (not its corner).  How would you calculate and use the center of the rectangle?

Comment: Well i think i will be wrong but center = rect.x / 2 and rect.Y / 2

Comment: That would get you halfway to the corner of the rectangle.  Your rectangle has a location **and** a size.  You need to take both of these things into account.

Comment: Well I'm too stupid for this :S

Comment: ...look how far you've progressed since you started this question!  Think about it this way.  Mathematically, how would you go to the corner of the rectangle, then go half the width and half the height to get to the center?

Comment: soooooo center=rect.widht/2 & rect.height/2 ?? :s

Comment: That would be true, but only if the rectangle was located at (0, 0).

Comment: int center = rect.Location.X + rect.Width / 2 & rect.Location.Y + rect.Width / 2;

Then maybe this?

Comment: Use a [Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and be sure to use the correct Width/Height with their respective X,Y values.

Comment: Afterwards, test it out by substituting your new Point called "center" for "rect" in the Paint() event where you're translating.

Comment: >< Sorry, but i said I'm very new at c#, so i barely understand what you are talking about. Thats why first i only asked for a complete code. Becaouse if someone send it to me. I can learn from it. And not just because im lazy.

Comment: It's just keeps getting harder step by step

Comment: Idle_Mind i sent you an e-mail on gmail, please read it!

Comment: You are **sooooooo** close.  Don't give up!  Here's a simple example of creating a Point: `Point ptA = new Point(411, 911);`  Then you could use `ptA.X` or `ptA.Y` in your code.

Comment: So i make a point like this:

Point centerpoint = new Point(rect.widht/2,rect.height/2);
and after this? how i make the square arount that centerpoint?

Comment: Did you make any headway with this Richard?  You literally have all the pieces you need to make it work.  Fix the Tick() event, then add one line to your Paint() event and change a couple variable names in there, then...boom!  **Magic!***

Comment: Nope, because I don't know what to fix in thick, and what to add to Paint() because I'm *******

Comment: Cany anyone tell me please??